# Getting "exec format error" while executing binary file

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    volatile int x;

    printf("without assignment %d", x);
    x = 100;
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

---

```
gcc -c -o volatandconstvolatile volatandconstvolatile.c
```

I got the `volatandconstvolatile` file but

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 naveenkumar naveenkumar      1600 Aug  8 05:12 volatandconstvolatile
```

then I changed the permissions `chmod 777 volatandconstvolatile`

then `./volatandconstvolatile`

```
./volatandconstvolatile: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
objdump volatandconstvolatile | grep "archit"
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000011:

readelf -a -W  volatandconstvolatile
```

I know that `volatile` is used to get the values from external means.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: The `-c` option tells `gcc` to compile to an object file without linking. So you have an object file. Leave out that option and it will work.

Comment: Running `file volatandconstvolatile /bin/sh` would show a big difference between the file types.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah No, `-o` just changes the output filename. The absence of a `.o` in the name doesn't make the file magically executable. See my answer. They needs to leave off the `-c`.

Comment: Easier still, just ask Make to compile and link for you: `make volatandconstvolatile`.

Comment: @TobySpeight `make` isn’t a cure-all. You still need to know the correct compiler commands to put in the Makefile.

Comment: @Tom - no need for a Makefile, for something this simple (that's why I suggested Make: start from its built-in rules, perhaps modify them by setting `CC`, `CFLAGS`, `LIBS` etc, before you either write a Makefile or your own command line).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I meant to say leave out the `-c` but I have a typing impediment....

Answer (score 3):

```
gcc -c -o volatandconstvolatile volatandconstvolatile.c
```

This compilation command line makes no sense.

`-c` means "compile only" and don't link. But you're leaving the `.o` suffix off, which implies that you're building a complete executable, which is wrong.

You can build your full application in one invocation of GCC like this, by leaving off the `-c`:

```
gcc -o volatandconstvolatile volatandconstvolatile.c
```

Note that LD sets the output binary's executable bit automatically. The fact that you had to `chmod` the file manually should have been a clue that something wasn't right.